# Filtering the Users only if conversation occurred

Tags: python, django, backend

Here's my Model

```
class Message(models.Model):
sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="sender")
receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="receiver")
msg_content = models.TextField()
```

How can I filter out the Users only if, either Current User have sent them a message or they have sent Current User a message, as we see on Social Networks?

I tried something like this

```
users = Message.objects.filter(Q(sender=request.user) | Q(receiver=request.user))
```

But it's not working. It's filtering the user equal number of times as conversation occured.

When i used

```
Message.objects.filter(Q(sender=user) | Q(receiver=user)).distinct('sender')
```

It's raising an error that "DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend" (sqlite3)

Please help me with this code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just `.distinct()` should work, no?

Comment: Change your db backend to one that supports DISTINCT.

Comment: Sorry to say but it doesn't

Comment: Should I opt PostgreSQL ?

Comment: switch to mysql or postgresql. They supports distinct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user something like this :
`users = User.objects.filter(sender__receiver__pk= request.user.id)`

or 
`users = User.objects.filter(sender__receiver= request.user)`

it returns all of users that send a message to current user!

Comment: Sir it says "Cannot resolve keyword 'message' into field."

Comment: let me check this.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir. The same logic suggested by you using Q lookup (for reverse action also) is working out perfectly. I wish if i had priviledge to give you bounty :)